# Howto use a blank space as a variable with SED

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace "a" by " " (single space) in a file, being " " (single space) a variable.
I don't get it. Following command doesn't work:

```
SRC="a" DST=" "; sed -i 's/'$SRC'/'$DST'/g' test.txt
```

I tried '\ ', "\ ", ' ', etc without success.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/'$SRC'/'$DST'/g' test.txt
```

is exactly the same as:

```
sed -i 's/a/' '/g' test.txt
```

so you are passing two distinct arguments to sed.  You could do:

```
sed -i "s/$SRC/$DST/g" test.txt
```

but if you insist on using `sed` it's probably better to do:

```
sed -i "y/$SRC/$DST/" test.txt
```

Comment: Sorry to come again: a new problem appeared when changing from ' to ". I get a mistake with "<". The real script is: sed -i "20,$s/$SRC/$DST<a href=.\/clients\/file.html>file<\/a> /1" test.txt

Comment: When you use `"`, variables are interpreted.  So the `$s` is a variable.  Escape the `$` (`\$`) or do: `sed -i '20,$'"s/$SRC..."`

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
$SRC="a" DST=" "; sed -i "s/$SRC/$DST/g" test.txt
```

shell var would be expanded between double quote .